# Arranging the values in ascending order in tableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios

In my application am using scrollView with 4 Buttons.
When we click on any one of the buttons a table will be displayed with data row by row dynamically.

Now my problem is to arrange them into ascending order.

Sample code is

this is for adding buttons to scrollview this is in one class

```
        browseScrollView.hidden = NO;
    browseScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(15, 57, 480, 44);
    [browseScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 40)];        
    firstButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [firstButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5,3,91,37)];
    [firstButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"genres.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    firstButton.tag = 1;
    [firstButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fourthPageSongSelction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [browseScrollView addSubview:firstButton];

    secondButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [secondButton setFrame:CGRectMake(110,3,91,37)];
    [secondButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"artists.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    secondButton.tag = 2;
    [secondButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fourthPageSongSelction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [browseScrollView addSubview:secondButton];

    thirdButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [thirdButton setFrame:CGRectMake(209,3,91,37)];
    thirdButton.tag = 3;
    [thirdButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"albums.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [thirdButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fourthPageSongSelction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [browseScrollView addSubview:thirdButton];


    fourthButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [fourthButton setFrame:CGRectMake(317,3,91,37)];
    fourthButton.tag = 4;
    [fourthButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"songs.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fourthButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fourthPageSongSelction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [browseScrollView addSubview:fourthButton];

    tableView.hidden = NO;
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 100, 235, 200);
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

This is the method i used to add values to table row this in another class which is subclass of TableViewCell

```
-(void) showFourthPageControlValues :(int) currRow :(int)val
{
int value = val;
TonifyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TonifyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

if (value == 1) 
{
    genresLabel1.hidden = NO;
    genresLabel2.hidden = NO;

    genresButton.hidden = NO;

    artistLabel1.hidden = YES;
    artistLabel2.hidden = YES;
    artistButton.hidden = YES;

    albumLabel1.hidden = YES;
    albumLabel2.hidden = YES;
    albumButton.hidden = YES;

    songsLabel1.hidden = YES;
    songsLabel2.hidden = YES;
    songsButton.hidden = YES;

    [genresLabel1 setText:[[appDelegate.songsList objectAtIndex:currRow] valueForKey:@"Genre"]];
    [genresLabel2 setText:[[appDelegate.songsList objectAtIndex:currRow] valueForKey:@"SongName"]];
    [genresButton addTarget:self.delegateController action:@selector(songTypeSelAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    genresButton.tag = currRow;
}

if (value == 2) 
{
    genresLabel1.hidden = YES;
    genresLabel2.hidden = YES;
    genresButton.hidden = YES;

    artistLabel1.hidden = NO;
    artistLabel2.hidden = NO;
    artistButton.hidden = NO;

    albumLabel1.hidden = YES;
    albumLabel2.hidden = YES;
    albumButton.hidden = YES;

    songsLabel1.hidden = YES;
    songsLabel2.hidden = YES;
    songsButton.hidden = YES;

    [artistLabel1 setText:[[appDelegate.songsList objectAtIndex:currRow] valueForKey:@"ArtistName"]];
    [artistLabel2 setText:[[appDelegate.songsList objectAtIndex:currRow] valueForKey:@"SongName"]];

    [artistButton addTarget:self.delegateController action:@selector(songTypeSelAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    artistButton.tag = currRow;
}
if (value == 3) 
{
    genresLabel1.hidden = YES;
    genresLabel2.hidden = YES;
    genresButton.hidden = YES;

    artistLabel1.hidden = YES;
    artistLabel2.hidden = YES;
    artistButton.hidden = YES;

    albumLabel1.hidden = NO;
    albumLabel2.hidden = NO;
    albumButton.hidden = NO;

    songsLabel1.hidden = YES;
    songsLabel2.hidden = YES;
    songsButton.hidden = YES;

    [albumLabel1 setText:[[appDelegate.songsList objectAtIndex:currRow] valueForKey:@"AlbumName"]];
    [albumLabel2 setText:[[appDelegate.songsList objectAtIndex:currRow] valueForKey:@"SongName"]];

    [albumButton addTarget:self.delegateController action:@selector(songTypeSelAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    albumButton.tag = currRow;
}
if (value == 4) 
{
    genresLabel1.hidden = YES;
    genresLabel2.hidden = YES;
    genresButton.hidden = YES;

    artistLabel1.hidden = YES;
    artistLabel2.hidden = YES;
    artistButton.hidden = YES;

    albumLabel1.hidden = NO;
    albumLabel2.hidden = NO;
    albumButton.hidden = NO;

    songsLabel1.hidden = NO;
    songsLabel2.hidden = NO;
    songsButton.hidden = NO;

    [songsLabel1 setText:[[appDelegate.songsList objectAtIndex:currRow] valueForKey:@"SongName"]];
    [songsLabel2 setText:[[appDelegate.songsList objectAtIndex:currRow] valueForKey:@"AlbumName"]];
    [songsButton addTarget:self.delegateController action:@selector(songTypeSelAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    songsButton.tag = currRow;
}
```

}

This is the method i am using for selection or row

```
-(void) songTypeSelAction :(id) sender
{
NSLog(@"songTypeSelAction");
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
NSLog(@"songTypeSelAction bttn.tag: %d", btn.tag);
if ([self.delegateController respondsToSelector:@selector(songImageSelAction:)])
{

}
}
```

Comment: actually am adding values to tableViewCell(row) dynamically, now i want to sort and add that values to tableViewCell(row).

Comment: For this you have to sort array (Data source)

Comment: @KalyanAndra - you facing errors or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"SongName" ascending:TRUE];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"AlbumName" ascending:TRUE];
[appDelegate.songsList sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor1,sortDescriptor2, nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ti preferable..Than you can do this..First take new view....Add four buttons and tableView.

Than follow this: Editor -> Embed In -> ScrollView

Than on button's click event show the table and Don't forget to reload tableview data at show time.

If having any query ask me.